# Working with Custom Lightning Components TrailHead challenge

Tags: salesforce

In the Salesforce.com Trai-lhead Challenge: "Working with Custom Lightning Components" we are asked to install an Unmanaged Package from App Exchange "Upgrade ContactsToday Component"

After installing this App Exchange package we are asked to add the new Custom Component to an App with Lightning App Builder. However, the Custom Component never shows up in the App Builder to select.  Viewing the installed package shows that component is installed (ContactsToday)

Is there something I am missing about adding a new Custom Component for use in the Lightning App Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup / Develop / Lightning Components / then check the checkbox Enable Lightning Components in Salesforce1 (BETA) and the component will show up in the App Builder.

Comment: this was helpful. they should update the trailhead with this info.